# How do I get a list of all iPhone users who use Activesync

Tags: powershell, iphone, activesync, calendar

It appears that IOS6 users [have an issue with meetings that are randomly being cancelled](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Bug-in-iOS-6-may-cancel-meetings-for-Exchange-users_id35157) and one fix may be to not ask users to upgrade.

How do I get a list of affected IOS users (not android or anything else), and tell them not to update to the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

The following command needs a filter, but will get the information that's needed.  Notably this will contain all activesync partnerships including those that are old and not used any more.  To filter this information, only retrieve records that have last contacted the server in X days.

The other aspect of improvement is how to retrieve the usernames from the following list.  This list gives the DN of the user, and if you need email addresses, then additional steps may be required.

```
 Get-ActiveSyncDevice | Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics | sort-object status, devicetype , lastsyncattempttime | ft  FirstSyncTime   ,LastPolicyUpdateTime   ,LastSyncAttemptTime    ,LastSuccessSync , DeviceType , DeviceID, DeviceAccessState, Identity –a
```

Additionally, with regard to that bug, make sure the "Automate Processing" value is set to AutoUpdate

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | Get-CalendarProcessing | Sort-Object AutomateProcessing | Select-Object Identity, AutomateProcessing | Export-Csv c:\CalUsers.csv
```